# Enable SSH access to my DD-WRT router TP LINK WR1043ND

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ssh, terminal

I would like to copy to the tmp directory on my router, and do not know how to enable SSH to access it.

I am connected to it via LAN and am running OSX Snow Leopard 10.5.6.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to search for the official documentation of DD-WRT ?

Here is the topic about SSH and telnet : http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Telnet/SSH_and_the_Command_Line

This explains how to setup the SSH daemon and authentication methods.

The following wiki article explains how to enable SSH and access your router from the internet : http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/SSH_access_from_internet

Basically, here are the steps :

1. **Ensure SSH Enabled**

   - Goto the Services tab and the Services sub-tab on the Web Interface
   - Enable "SSHd" is under the section titled "Secure Shell"
   - 'SSH TCP Forwarding' does not need to be enabled if you just want to connect from the outside to your LAN.
   - Choose an appropriate port (The default is 22, but it is recommended that you change it to a non-standard port above 1024 for security reasons. Remember the port number, as you will need to enter it into your SSH client in order to connect to the router)
   - You can activate (less secure) password authorization and/or (recommended) private/public key authorization. More information about generating the keys can be found here: [[1](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Telnet/SSH_and_the_Command_Line)].
   - Save
2. **Enable Remote Access**

   - Goto the Administration tab and the Management sub-tab on the Web Interface
   - Enable "SSH Management" under the section titled "Remote Access"
   - Enter the same port number as specified under (4) above. This opens the port in the firewall.
   - Save
   - Reboot Router

Now you will be able to connect to your router's WAN IP from the internet using an SSH client such as PuTTY.

**Disabling Remote Access**

If at any time you wish to disable SSH access from the WAN,
- Goto the Administration tab and the Management sub-tab on the Web Interface
- Disable "SSH Management" under the section titled "Remote Access"
- Apply Settings

**SSH Password**

- When asked for the username, enter root (even if you changed username in web interface)
- When asked for the password, enter your router's password

Hope this helps !

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Corrected my answer, with the steps.